# Game doesn't appear in software center but I can find it in APT

Tags: package-management, software-center, games

I wanted to install the game *UFO: Alien Invasion* in Ubuntu 17.10. It is available in repositories, as we can see here:

- [UFOAI wiki](https://ufoai.org/wiki/Download)
- [Ubuntu packages search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ufoai&searchon=names)

With `apt` I find it:

```
$ apt search ufoai
...
ufoai/artful 2.5-3 amd64
  UFO: Alien Invasion -- build your team and stop the aliens
```

(and numerous additional results for related packages
)
However, in Software Center it doesn't appear, nor can I find it by searching or browsing the games category. I have main, universe, restricted and multiverse repos enabled.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This had been reported as a bug ([Bug#1553211](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1553211) and [Bug#157945](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1579415)). To summarize the notes, It is by design that the Software Center does not show all software packages.

Instead use **Synaptic package manager**, which shows much more software and has better control of package management. To install run:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Then run:

`sudo synaptic`

Comment: Those bugs comments say that only desktop applications are shown in Software Center. This is a Game, so it is a Desktop application. After installing it via apt, it appears among my applications in Gnome Shell menus.

Comment: And by their comments it should have appeared in the software center but it does not as many other programs don't. They also do not plan on fixing it. I think you will be much happier with Synaptic.